# Can I rate an application in software center without writing a review for it?

Tags: 11.04, software-center

Can I just rate an application in the Ubuntu Software Center without having to write a complete review?
I only get a window with SSO and a review text and rating.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this section](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SoftwareCenter/RatingsAndReviews#with%20empty%20review%20text%20or%20summary,%20or%20no%20rating) of [the specification](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SoftwareCenter/RatingsAndReviews) it appears to be on purpose, probably to discourage people from voting without giving a reason why:

> The review service should reject with an error any review that does not have all of review text, summary, and a rating.

Comment: Well said. I didn't think to take a look at the docs.